# Textview clickable false not working

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

How can i make textview Clickable false ? I tried with `textView.setClickable(false)` but it is not working i add my snippet below.

```
t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_View1);

                t1.setClickable(false);
                //t1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                //t1.setEnabled(false);

                t1.setFocusable(false);

                t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        t1.setText("clicked");
                        }
                });
```

But when i click on textview text is change kindly help me.

Comment: Can also use `t1.setOnClickListener(null);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to change the listener position like this

```
t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         t1.setText("clicked");
     }
});
t1.setClickable(false);
//t1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
//t1.setEnabled(false);

t1.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Why adding  android:clickable="false" in xml is not working as well.

Comment: Because setting an `onClickListener` overrides `setClickable(false)`

Answer (score 7):

You need fully disable TextView:

```
t1.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This is not answer for this question, The question is why setting clickable is not disabling onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have links in the `TextView` make sure you didn't set `movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()`. Probably `android:autoLink="web"` has been set.